# SurfaceView onDraw skips drawing

Tags: android, surfaceview, ondraw

My surfaceview onDraw method sometimes skips drawing some bitmaps on the screen and once it skips it never draws the particular bitmaps again.
My code

```
public class Board extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
 //varaibles declared here
public Board(){
    //initaializations here
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
 }
//my onDraw method
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
   for(int u = 0;u<6; u++){
      ai.get(u).draw(canvas);//each of these objects draws something on the screen.
      human.get(u).draw(canvas);
   }
   postInvalidate();
 }

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
gameLoop = new GameLoop(this);
gameLoop.start();
}
```

The onDraw() method is called every 100milliseconds in a thread that runs the game loop.

```
public class GameLoop extends Thread{
     Board board;
     private final int DELAY = 100;
     public GameLoop(Board board){
      this.board=board;
     }

   protected void run(){
     long beforeTime,timediff,sleep;
     beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     while(running)
     {
       Canvas c = null;
       try{
           c=board.getHolder.lockCanvas();
           synchronized(board.getHolder()){
              board.onDraw(c);
          }finally{
           if(c!=null)
             board.getHolder.unlockCanvas(c);
          }
      timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis - beforeTime;
      sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;
      if(sleep<0)
        sleep = 10;
      try{
         Thread.sleep(sleep);
      }catch(InterruptedException e){}
      beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   }
}
```

So this skips happen like this: sometimes(in the onDraw() method) when u=0 does not draw or u = 5, it could be u = any of the possible values and the rest draws and once it skips that values it keeps skipping it everytime the onDraw method is called. I hope I have been able to make it clear enough.
I would appreciate help to resolve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As is, you are updating your main UI thread from another thread.  Android docs indicate that this leads to unpredictable behavior, which you are experiencing.

Consider subclassing AsyncTask to do your threading for you.  There are routines for doing background work and posting to the main UI thread from the UI thread itself.

Basically, you call execute on the task, which then calls it's doInBackground routine and when it is done, it calls onPostExecute routine with the results of the task.

These sources should be useful in helping to understand the problem and subclass AsyncTask:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thanks Cam. i fixed it by postInvalidating in the gameLoop thread and not in the onDraw method and it works fine so far.